# Simplest way to update website content without editing the page

Tags: php, html

I've built a [website](http://www.bestofthebiro.com) for a friend and because he is not very techy and will be updating it relatively often.

My question is is there a way I can update the site using say, a PHP form and that will write a new div into the page?

So in standard english it would be the following:

- Enter title
- Enter date
- Enter poster
- Enter content
- Submit

Can I do that simply in PHP? I'm open to other suggestions as well.

Thanks a lot!
Liam

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I highly suggest you "Inplace Editing"

- http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/jeditable
- http://code.google.com/p/jquery-in-place-editor/
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/708801/whats-the-best-edit-in-place-plugin-for-jquery

The user has only to point and click on elements which he want to change. Plain simple... It's on you to implement an basic authentication system so that only the Owner of the Page is allowed to edit and save Data.

Comment: That word again... It's authentication BTW.

Comment: Sorry, i'm not an native english speaker. "Authentifizierung" is the german word for authentication. Many english words are easy translatable only by changing a letter October=>Oktober for example.

Comment: And i'm quite sure if take a closer look you'll find many more mistakes. And that's ok for me because you can get the meaning of my thoughts :)

Comment: No worries. It's just that that word seems be misspelled by a lot of people. :)

Comment: Now you know why. Authentifizierung=>Authentication ;)

Comment: Any idea where there is info on making a save.php function?

Comment: Hopefully in your brain ;) IMHO the Data is send via HTTP-POST so it's simple to access the data via $_POST-Array. You need to validate and write the data to a database, textfile or what ever you want to store your data in. I've no idea about your php knowledge so it's difficult to answer...

Comment: :) ok well thats a start - I can create a database and write to it easily enough that will be no problem. I suppose what I'm trying to get my head around is how jeditable works, I can get it working so its clickable and editable, it was more when I click ok and execute the PHP what happens and how is that then displayed back on the webpage. Do I write to the database and then POST that data on to the HTML page, therefore every time I update that part of the database it is reflected on the page?

Comment: Exactly. That's the way how you handle those data.

Comment: Cool thanks! I'll create that then. Thanks for all your help.

Answer (score 0):

All in all it's just the editing of a file. You can write a php script that takes that input from the user and basically rewrites the html page accordingly.

Comment: you'll also need to communicate with FTP if this site is live

Comment: if you're feeling really fancy, you can put this script on the server-make it password protected and basically you can add content from anywhere you'd like.